# Report that shows Tasks created by a group of users changes when tasks change owner

Tags: reporting, tasks

I have a simple report that shows tasks created by a small group of internal users.  For some reason when an owner of a task is changed that shows up in this report is changed it disappears from the report. But the report parameters haven't changed, it should still show the task even though the owner has changed.  Is this some gotcha of Tasks, changing the owner also affects the CreatedBy value as well?  Anyone run into this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Providing the fact that all the parameters of the report remains the same, and the changed owner is present within those parameters, the reason why you might not be able see the data belonging to this owner is that you have restricted access to all the data in your org. Try to check under the profile setting if any restrictions have been enabled on your profile. 
Another reason might be due to the fact that your profile hierarchy level is below the other user's profile which it won't allow you to see his/her data.

With regards to the CreatedBy values, they are unchangeable by default, you would need to contact Salesforce support to make changes to this field, hence it is highly unlikely that changing the Owner would impact the CreatedBy field.